# ConcurrentModificationException in spite of using Iterator

Tags: exception, iterator, concurrentmodification

I am using the following class:

```
public class Ticker implements Runnable {

private LinkedList<Timeable> timeables = new LinkedList<>();

@Override
public void run() {

    ListIterator<Timeable> it = timeables.listIterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next().tick();
    }
}

public void add(Timeable timeable) {
    timeables.add(timeable);
}

public void remove(Timeable timeable) {
    timeables.remove(timeable);
}
```

}

I thought iterators prevent the ConcurrentModificationException but it throws one at "it.next().tick();".

How can I solve this?

Comment: What code is in the `click()` method? Show any nested calls that result in the list being changed

Answer (score 0):

The java collection classes are fail-fast, so `LinkedList` will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if its structure is  modified by one thread while another thread is in the process of iterating over its elements.

For multithreaded code you should use a thread safe collection such as `CopyOnWriteArrayList` (which provides a fail safe iterator of the collection at a point in time) or `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` (if you only need access to the first or last element).